# Реализация метода Ньютона(С++)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика

Необходимо реализовать метод Ньютона для поиска корня уравнения `tan(7 * x) + x^2*sin(x) + 1 = 0`. Вот мой код

```
int main()
{
    double x0; //Грубое приближение
    double eps; //Шаг(точность)
    double a, b; //Границы интервала
    double amendment; //Поправка к значению х0
    double s; //Solution - решение
    double x1;



    // Начальная функция = tan(7 * x) + x*x*sin(x) + 1; - начальная функция
    // Производная от этой функции = (7 / (pow(cos(7*x), 2)) + 2 * x*sin(x) + x*x*cos(x)); 

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Введите грубое приближение x0, EPS и нажмите Enter" << endl;
    cin >> x0 >> eps;
    cout << "Введите границы интервала [a;b]" << endl;
    cin >> a >> b;

    if (eps < 0)
        cout << "Ошибка! Шаг не может быть отрицательным числом!" << endl;
    if (x0 > b || x0 < a)
        cout << "Ошибка! Грубое приближения корня х0 должно входить в промежуток [a,b]!" << endl;

    do
    {
        amendment = ((-1)*tan(7 * x0) + x0*x0*sin(x0) + 1) / ((7 / (pow(cos(7 * x0), 2)) + 2 * x0*sin(x0) + x0*x0*cos(x0)));
        x1 = x0 + amendment;
        if (tan(7 * x1) + x1*x1*sin(x1) + 1 == 0)
            break;
        x0 = x1;
    }
    while ((tan(7 * x1) + x1*x1*sin(x1) + 1 != 0));

    s = x1;
    cout << "Корень уравнения = " << s << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Но с моим кодом получается бесконечный цикл. Что я упустил, как лучше исправить проблему?

—

Алгоритм метода Ньютона:

1. Находим грубое приближение корня `X0`.
2. Вычисляем поправку к значению `X0`: `Dx = -f(X0)/f'(X0)`.
3. Новое значение `X1 = X0 + Dx`.
4. Проверка условия `f(X1) = 0`.
5. Если не удовлетворены, идем на шаг 2, но уже с `x = х1`.

Comment: вполне вероятно, что вы будете крутиться вокруг нуля до бесконечности, попробуйте проверять не на равенство нулю, а на соответствие некоторому епсолон `while  ((tan(7 * x1) + x1*x1*sin(x1) + 1 < 0.000000001));`

Comment: Да и в принципе делать точное сравнение переменных `double` либо `float` очень редко бывает верно, они почти всегда существуют в памяти с погрешностью.

Comment: А вас не смущает, что введенное `eps` нигде в программе не используется?

Answer (score 4):

1. На тему `eps` всё сказано, вместо условия `y != 0` необходимо использовать условие `|y| > eps`.
2. В формуле для `amendent` знак минус должен относиться ко всему числителю, а не только к тангенсу.
3. Производная вычислена верно.